# Flask Restful and Flask SocketIO server run together

Tags: flask-restful, flask-socketio

I'm trying to use Flask Restful and Flask SocketIO at the same time. I already made a Flask Restful application but now I want to use Flask SocketIO to have realtime communication between client and my server.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
socketio = SocketIO()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
    app.run(port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Once I run this, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
    socketio.run(app, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 475, in run
    if self.server.eio.async_mode == 'threading':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'eio'
```

I'm a beginner in coding with Flask. Hope you could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flask-Restful does not change anything with regards to how you start your server. You can do:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The code you pasted in your question had a bug that was causing the `AttributeError`, and that was that you were not passing the `app` instance to the `SocketIO` constructor.